# how to redirect from nonfoundpage on nuxt3?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt3

need to redirect all routes to /

on nuxt3 try this, on defineNuxtConfig
`routeRules: { '*': { redirect: '/', }`
but ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS